# Why would a ceiling fan not work after installation?

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

Replaced a ceiling fan thinking the motor was faulty, however the new one is not turning on.

I wired the fan following the instructions below without luck. I’m using wago connectors to connect the wires.

I also noticed an additional wire coming from the ceiling without covering or color which I connected to the blue wire to see if that worked but no luck. I am hoping I did not damage the fan but besides this, what else could be the reasons for the fan not functioning?

[image]

The wiring is per the instructions. Black and blue to black, white to white, green to ground screw. There is also a bare wire which I covered with a wire cap. I will be checking voltage of each wire once the tester comes in.

[image]

The switch has red yellow and black wires connected which correspond with the wall light outside but I don’t see any white wires connected which the ceiling fan does have. Could this be the cause of the problem?

[image]

I am also in the process of installing a ring can to the wall light outside which uses the same outlet. Pics of the wiring provided. I would like the switch to work both with the ceiling fan and the wall light outside. The ceiling fan would use the right switch and wall light left switch.

[image]

Comment: Good chance you tripped the breaker.  You connected ground to hot.  Green or bare wires are ground and connecting them to any other coloured wire is bad.  If the breaker is not tripped, then you have bigger problems(bad panel).

Comment: Model of fan? Does it have a remote?

Comment: Pictures of how you _actually_ wired it would be super helpful. Most of us who would answer your question would have a pretty good idea of how it's _supposed_ to be wired... :)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Here is the model of the fan. Hampton bay RDB9144-BN 44” ceiling fan. There is no remote.

Comment: @FreeMan Picture has been uploaded, I hope it’s clear. I’m waiting on voltage tester to check the power on each wire. The instruction diagram and fan model provided above.

Comment: I'm guessing the old fan was fine and someone just threw a switch you weren't aware of... Generally, check for power before replacing hardware

Comment: @isherwood pic of the switch provided. I don’t see a white cable connecting to the switch which there is one connecting to the fan. One of these connects to the wall light outside.

Comment: Please keep cables and wires straight. A wire is a metal conductor (copper or aluminum) inside a layer of insulation (except bare ground wires). A cable is **two or more** wires inside an outer wrapping ("sheath"). Wires may also (as is the case here) be inside plastic or metal **conduit**. The problem is cables often have a white sheath, so "don't see a white cable" is very different from "don't see a white wire". And in fact, with conduit (which you have) you will **not** see any cables and you won't see a *white wire* on a "dumb" switch, only (some of the time) on "smart switches".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Yes, disregard cables as I meant wires for all post above.

Comment: There is no "outlet" (receptacle) in this scenario, by the way. You maybe meant "junction box". What is a "ring can"? Is that "Ring cam(era)"? How much of this wiring has been recently changed?

Comment: Also, the wiring in the wall light box suggests that it was part of a three-way circuit at some point. I think we need to start fresh with a better idea of what cable goes where and which are home runs.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to figure out. The wires from both the switch for the ceiling fan and the wall lamp were routed towards the junction box outside where the ring cam was install thus why there were so many wire coming from this box. Three of these wires for the wall lamp and three for the ceiling lamp so after figuring out which wire corresponded to what switch and some wiring, both the camera and the ceiling were connected and are working properly. Apologies if there are error in some of the terminology.